# CSS - Vertical Align with no Height

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I'm trying to vertically align text in a box that has a height that changes to match the width (so that it's a perfect square). I just cannot get it to work. I have **2 issues**:

1. I'm trying to vertically align the text within the "smallbox" class.
2. Besides this, I also cannot get the "text" class to vertically align either.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RTJGD/)

Here's my CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    background: yellow;
    font-size: 2.5vmin;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    /*width: 200vmin;*/
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    /*padding-bottom: 5vmin;*/
    padding-bottom: 2.5%;
}
.smallbox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 16.8%;
    border-radius: 2vmin;
    font-size: 6vmin;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
.smallbox b {
    margin-top: 100%;
    display: block;
    zoom: 1.0;
}

.smallbox p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.content {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 28vmin;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 2vmin;
    font-size: 3.5vmin;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 5vmin;
}
.content:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: -4.75vmin;
    top: 13.5vmin;
    border-top: 3vmin solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3vmin solid transparent; 
    border-right: 5vmin solid white;
}
.title {
    height: 5vmin;
    padding: .75vmin 1.5vmin;
    border-radius: 2vmin 2vmin 1vmin 1vmin;
    margin: .5vmin;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
.text {
    padding: .5vmin 2vmin;
    text-align: center;
}
.left {
    padding: .5vmin 2vmin;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.right {
    padding: .5vmin 2vmin;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2vmin 2vmin 2vmin 2vmin;
    margin: .5vmin;
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
.right a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.arrowleft {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="box.css">
    </head>
<body>
<div id="container">
        <div class="box">
                <div class="smallbox"><b></b><p>Onceuponatimeinafarawayland</p></div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">Some Title</div>
                    <div class="text"><p>This is just some example text here</p>
</div>
                    <div class="left">Left</div>
                    <a href=""><div class="right">Right</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>





</div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
.smallbox p:before{
content:" ";
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
height:100%;
width:1px;
}
.smallbox p span{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
width:99%;
}
```

Credit goes to [Paul](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?996098-Vertical-Align-with-no-Height&p=5349227&viewfull=1#post5349227).

Comment: It doesn't look like this works properly with more then one line though?

Comment: Actually, it is one of the few techniques that will work properly with more than one line. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQAU4/)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `position: absolute;` on the paragraph within the `.smallbox` class which is forcing it to display block, so vertical-align will have no effect. In the fiddle below I used the `line-height` property to align the `.smallbox` text though I don't think that'll work with a dynamic height.

[I also centered](http://jsfiddle.net/RTJGD/3/)  the `.text` class paragraph by adding `display: inline-block;` and using the `px` value for vertical-align. Just adjust it to your needs.

Comment: thanks, that fixed the .text class paragraph, but I'm still struggling with the .smallbox. Is there any other way to make a square besides the way I used but with its contained text vertically aligned?